# Swift: Dictionary Key as CGRect

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I need to save the `frame` of a `button` as a key and the `index` from an array as its `value`.  Below is the code:

```
var buttonLocationWithIndex = Dictionary<CGRect, Int>()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for (index, point) in enumerate(self.points){
        let pointButton = UIButton()
        pointButton.frame = point.bounds
        self.buttonLocationWithIndex[point.frame] = index
        self.view.addSubview(pointButton)
    }
```

I'm getting an error when trying to declare the dictionary: `Type 'CGRect' does not confirm to protocol 'Hashable'`

**UPDATE**

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    var alertView = UIAlertView();

    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok");
    alertView.title = "title";
    var boundsIndex = self.buttonLocationWithIndex[sender.frame]
    var value = self.points(boundsIndex)
    alertView.message = value
    alertView.show();
}
```

**Error:** `Cannot invoke points with an arguments list of type (Int?)'`

Comment: self.points(boundsIndex) needs to be self.points[boundsIndex]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `Hashable` protocol on `CGRect` trough an extension.

```
extension CGRect: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(origin.x)
        hasher.combine(origin.y)
        hasher.combine(size.width)
        hasher.combine(size.height)
    }
}
```

It will allow you to use `CGRect` as a key.

Comment: I tried this in the same class, but I get an error:  `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSStringFromRect'`

Comment: Did you import Foundation?

Comment: Can you post more code? Here is a working example http://swiftstub.com/963578307/?v=gm

Comment: @ABakerSmith No, you can check it here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromRect

Comment: @Tomáš Linhart, that says `NSStringFromRect` takes an `NSRect`, not a `CGRect`.

Comment: On `iOS` that would be `NSStringFromCGRect` but if you want to use it for hash, you should also use it for equality.

Comment: How do I access the dictionary?          `let arrayIndex = self.buttonLocationWithIndex[sender.frame]`  It says Expected expression in assignment.

Comment: Can you post more code? A single line like this is correct, a problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think going through a string is efficient.

Answer (score 6):

**Update (2021-11-01):**
The accepted answer was edited to provide a similar solution to mine, so it also works.

---

This is an old question, but since I recently needed this, I thought this could be useful to someone else.

The current way to implement the Hashable protocol for CGRect in Swift 5 is:

```
import UIKit

extension CGRect: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(minX)
        hasher.combine(minY)
        hasher.combine(maxX)
        hasher.combine(maxY)
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable